Raspberry Pi 5 - Blinking green LED Error
I bought a raspberry pi 5 4GB and when i plug my ethernet cable, micro sd card with pi os and a 5V 3A USB-C power supply , basically it starts to blink green three times over and over with an interval in the middle of the 3 blinks.
I want to get the IP address so I can connect to my raspberry using SSH, but I can not find it using either an IP scanner or even seeing all devices connected to my router using the router admin page.
Anyone knows what is the problem?
I tried to connect a hdmi cable to my monitor to see if i get any display but with no success.
I also tried different micro sd cards (all with more than 32GB) and even more power supplies.
Also my ethernet cable works for any of my devices ( except for the raspberry pi)
